# Is there any way to optimize time and path simultaneously?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I have a problem with time and path optimization. I couldn't define two objectives for both time and path simultaneously. Python reads the last objective and gives result according to that way.
Could you please help me to solve this optimization problem? Thanks..

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Time points
nt = 501                    # nt=101
tm = np.linspace(0, 1, nt)  # tm = np.linspace(0, 100, nt)
m.time = tm

# Variables
g = m.Const(value=9.80665)
V = m.Const(value=200)  # velocity

Xi = m.Var(value=0, lb=-2*np.pi, ub=2*np.pi)       # Heading angle  value=-np.pi dene
x = m.Var(value=0, lb=-100000, ub=100000)      # x position
y = m.Var(value=0, lb=-100000, ub=100000)      # y position

pathx = m.Const(value=70000)  # intended distance in x direction
pathy = m.Const(value=20000)  # intended distance in y direction

p = np.zeros(nt) # final time=1
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000000  # iteration number

# Optimize Final Time
tf = m.FV(value=1.0, lb=0.0001, ub=1000.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# Controlled parameters
Mu = m.MV(value=0, lb=-1, ub=1)  # solver controls bank angle
Mu.STATUS = 1
Mu.DCOST = 1e-3

# Equations
m.Equation(x.dt() == tf * (V * (m.cos(Xi))))  
m.Equation(y.dt() == tf * (V * (m.sin(Xi))))  
m.Equation(Xi.dt() == tf * (g * m.tan(Mu)) / V )

# Objective Function
w = 1e4
m.Minimize(w * (x * final - pathx) ** 2)  # 1D part (x)
m.Minimize(w * (pathy - y * final) ** 2)  # 2D part (y)

m.Obj(tf)
'''
```

Comment: Here is an application that does 3D path optimization of High Altitude Long Endurance Aircraft: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/hale-trajectory I'll also give some suggestions on your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple objectives are combined into a single objective with summation in Gekko. If there are multiple separate objectives that should be considered separately then a Pareto front is a possible approach to evaluate the tradeoff (see [Section 6.5](https://apmonitor.com/me575/uploads/Main/chap6_genetic_evolutionary_optimization_v2.pdf) of the [Optimization book](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/BookChapters)). However, this isn't implemented in Gekko.

One correct is that `m.Equation(y * final <= pathy )` should be `m.Equation((y-pathy) * final <= 0)` to avoid a potential infeasible solution if `pathy<0`.

[image: Solution]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Gekko model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Time points
nt = 51                    # nt=101
tm = np.linspace(0, 1, nt)  # tm = np.linspace(0, 100, nt)
m.time = tm

# Variables
g = m.Const(value=9.80665)
V = m.Const(value=200)  # velocity

Xi = m.Var(value=0, lb=-2*np.pi, ub=2*np.pi)       # Heading angle  value=-np.pi dene
x = m.Var(value=0, lb=-100000, ub=100000)      # x position
y = m.Var(value=0, lb=-100000, ub=100000)      # y position

pathx = m.Const(value=70000)  # intended distance in x direction
pathy = m.Const(value=20000)  # intended distance in y direction

p = np.zeros(nt) # final time=1
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000000  # iteration number

# Optimize Final Time
tf = m.FV(value=1.0, lb=0.0001, ub=1000.0)
tf.STATUS = 1

# Controlled parameters
Mu = m.MV(value=0, lb=-1, ub=1)  # solver controls bank angle
Mu.STATUS = 1
Mu.DCOST = 1e-3

# Equations
m.Equation(x.dt() == tf * (V * (m.cos(Xi))))  
m.Equation(y.dt() == tf * (V * (m.sin(Xi))))  
m.Equation(Xi.dt() == tf * (g * m.tan(Mu)) / V )

m.Equation((x-pathx) * final <= 0)
m.Equation((y-pathy) * final <= 0)

# Objective Function
w = 1e4
m.Minimize(w * (x * final - pathx) ** 2)  # 1D part (x)
m.Minimize(w * (y * final - pathy) ** 2)  # 2D part (y)

#in here python reads the last objective how can i run this two objectives simultaneously.
#m.Obj(Xi * final) 
m.Minimize(tf)

#m.Maximize(0.2 * mass * final)  # objective function
m.options.IMODE = 6
#m.options.NODES = 2
#m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
#m.options.SOLVER = 3
# m.open_folder() # to search for infeasibilities
m.solve(disp=False)
print('Final Time: ' + str(tf.value[0]))
tm = np.linspace(0,tf.value[0],nt)
#tm = tm * tf.value[0]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
fig.suptitle('Results')
axs[0].plot(tm, Mu.value, 'b-', lw=2, label=r'$Bank$')
axs[0].legend(loc='best')
axs[1].plot(tm, x.value, 'r--', lw=2, label=r'$x$')
axs[1].legend(loc='best')
axs[2].plot(tm, y.value, 'p-', lw=2, label=r'$y$')
axs[2].legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
#plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()


plt.figure()
plt.plot(x.value, y.value)
plt.show()
```